# implementing a typeahead with bootstrap input-group class

Tags: angular, autocomplete, bootstrap-4

I want to implement a proper typeahead search feature in my angular application.
At present, this it how it works.

[no-input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar9dJ.png)

[medium-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fTVz.png)

[small-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPhcx.png)

I want to implement it like this,where the dropdown doesn't disturb other elements.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wxVO.png)

Here is the code,

**template-html**

```html
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm ">

          <div class="input-group mb-3 ">
            <input [formControl]="queryField" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type any location"
              aria-label="locationName" aria-describedby="button-addon2">

            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-success" type="button" id="button-addon2">Search</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group" *ngIf="locations.length>0">
            <li *ngFor="let location of locations" class="list-group-item">
              {{location.title}}
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>



        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a restaurant" aria-label="restaurantName"
            aria-describedby="button-addon2">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-success" type="button" id="button-addon2">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 library doesn't provide a typeahead component out of the box. However, Angular's wrapper libraries for bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap and ng-bootstrap both provides a typeahead component.

ngx-bootstrap: 
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead

ng-bootstrap:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

The code required to create a typeahead is also very little, e.g. using ngx-bootstrap :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selected"
       [typeahead]="states"
       class="form-control">
```

You don't have to recreate a typeahead feature using raw html and css. Also, I'd suggest that you use one of these wrapper libraries instead of using the original bootstrap library which would require you to use jquery on top of Angular.

Comment: Actually the project is an assignment which mentioned to create an autocomplete feature without using any external NPM module or library .

Comment: But you are using bootstrap 4...?

Comment: We are  permitted to use bootstrap only for css components and grid. The auto complete feature should be built from scratch.